# Logback %replace does it compile the regex for each log statement?

Tags: java, logging, logback

Does the logback %replace function on message with regex replacment compiles the regex for each log statement printed.

Seems %replace is taking lot of cpu with regex usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `%replace` causes Logback to engage `ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.ReplacingCompositeConverter`. This converter is instanced **and** started when the pattern layout is started i.e. when Logback configures itself.

The `ReplacingCompositeConverter.start()` method compiles the pattern:

```
public void start() {
    ...
    regex = optionList.get(0);
    pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    replacement = optionList.get(1);
    super.start();
}
```

And then each time Logback encounters a log entry which uses a pattern containing `%replace`, it delegates to `ReplacingCompositeConverter.transform()` which applies the pattern:

```
protected String transform(E event, String in) {
    ...
    return pattern.matcher(in).replaceAll(replacement);
}
```

So, Logback does **not** compile the `%replace` pattern for "each log statement printed".

Comment: `delegates to ReplacingCompositeConverter.start()`, surely `delegates to ReplacingCompositeConverter.transform()`?

Comment: D'oh copy-pasta error. I _did_ include the correct method statement but referred to it as the `start()` method. Thanks for spotting that.